# react-native couchbase lite filter by key

Tags: react-native, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I have created a mobile app using react-native and I use couchbase for syncing purposes. I have used the module for this. 
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/react-native-couchbase-lite

According to the documentation I can filter from a key using queryView method. But in my application I can only filter integer values using queryView method. when I use queryView method for strings, it does not filter values from the documents, it just return all the documents from the relevant type. Following way I have defined my views.

```
        views: {
          person_view: {
            map: 'function (doc) { if (doc.type === "Person") { emit(doc.name, null);} }'
          },
        }
```

following is by filter method.

```
  filterDocumentByAttribute(view, key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let options = {
        key: key,
        include_docs: true
      };
      this.database.queryView(DESIGN_DOCUMENT_NAME, view, options)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.rows);
        resolve(res.rows);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  }
```

when the key parameter is integer the method works perfectly, but when it is a string it just return all documents.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in https://github.com/couchbaselabs/react-native-couchbase-lite/blob/master/index.js

The code calls `JSON.stringify` on the value for a supplied `key` parameter, which is slightly tricky in how it handles quotes.  The Mozilla docs have a pretty good discussion [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for more.